# How can I document a 'this' instance inside a callback function in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webstorm, jsdoc

Having this code:

```
function Element() {
    this.name = "yay";
}
Element.prototype.extend = function(object) {
    if (object instanceof Object) {
        for (var n in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                this[n] = object[n];
            }
        }
    }
};

var el = new Element();
el.extend({
    update: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
});
```

I want WebStorm to know that `update()` `this` is an instance of `Element`, but I don't really know how to do it.

The maximum I've reached is this:

```
el.extend({
    /**
      * @this Element
      */
    update: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
});
```

But I don't want to do that in every `extend()`.

Also found this:

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} FunctionExtend
 */
/**
 * @param {FunctionExtend} object
 */
Element.prototype.extend = function(object) {
    [...]
```

But I'm stuck in:

- How to declare `FunctionExtend` to have undefined number of parameters.
- How to tell that each `@parameter` will be a callback without knowing the parameter name.
- How to tell what is the `@this` of the callbacks.

Comment: it doesn't seem possible - how do you expect to know the **value** of `this` (which is determined in runtime) before the execution? what if someone re`bind`s the context of `Element.prototype.extend`? the value of `this` will than change, rendering the docs obsolete.

Comment: Because is an engine made by myself and I just want to avoid this message in the IDE: http://i.imgur.com/FJg6yOh.png, which I can avoid with this: http://i.imgur.com/KjiRSDA.png, but don't want to do that in every function, so I was thinking if there's a way of doing it in the extend function instead.

Comment: i see. well, **a)** you should ask the **real** question you're concerned about, i.e. "how to avoid the ___ message in webstorm IDE?", and **b)** perhaps you should just turn off that specific inspection in webstorm so it stops bugging you :)

Comment: Yeah yeah, I know that I can do that, but I don't want to turn off that specific inspection in the entire document, so I asked the other question because I noticed that setting @this "correctly" fixes it. Maybe I should rethink how I implement custom methods. Before extending prototypes I was thinking on creating another class that inherits the main class but I wanted to avoid that because that makes the project more complex, but I think that I have to give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending prototypes to begin with is generally a Bad Idea™, and it does not play well with write-time documentation tools like JSDoc.

You will probably have no choice but to document every function individually.

Comment: I just added a comment up there. I semi-copy it here. So is impossible to avoid these messages in the IDE: http://i.imgur.com/FJg6yOh.png? When I extend using jQuery, it don't shows the error: http://i.imgur.com/XtRht51.png. Why?

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Have you tried inspecting how the `jQuery.fn.extend` function is documented (or implemented)? There may be clues there. (It's worth noting that it's *still* a bad idea to extend prototypes in that way. jQuery is no exception)

Comment: Hmm, yeah, you are right. When I extend the prototype, I first check if there's already another prototype of that name, to avoid overriding, but that's such a hack. The same as I said before, I already posted a comment above but I semi-copy it here. Before extending prototypes I was thinking on extending the base class with another class, but just to add one or two functions in some part of the code I don't saw the needs of making the project more complex, but I guess that finally I'm going to do it that way. Surely in the future I'm going to be grateful of this decision. +1™

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Have you considered composition over inheritance?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Don't thought about it, but I'm really thankful :P I'm definitely going with that. Is almost the same as prototype extending but with known classes, so keeps the OOP flow. I love it.